# How to iterate List<Map<String, Object>> in aura component

Tags: apex, aura, map, aura-iteration

I want to iterate over List<Map<String, Object>>. I'm not sure how to do it. Below is the response I am getting from apex class to aura controller.

```
[{"label":"Test 1","name:"Test Value},{"label":"Test 2","name":"Test Value"},{"label":"Test 3","name":"Test Value"}].
```

Below is the code I tried.

JS Side:

```
var custs = [];
var conts = response.getReturnValue(); //List<Map<String, Object>>
for ( var key in conts) {
    custs.push({value:conts[key], key:key});
}
component.set("v.totalResult", custs);
```

HTML Side :

```
<aura:attribute name= "totalResult" type="List" />
```

Can anyone let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[aura:iteration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:iteration/example)** to iterate over a list

```html
<aura:iteration items="{!v.totalResult}" var="item">
 <p>Name : {!item.name}</p>
 <p>Label: {!item.label}</p>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: My bad !! Thanks a lot !!  By seeing the Map inside the List, I got confused. It works now